# How to correctly use QGraphicsLinearLayout together with QGraphicsScene in order to position QGraphicsItems?

Tags: qt, layout, qgraphicsscene

I'm struggling with getting `QGraphicsLinearLayout` to work together with `QGraphicsScene` such that a group of `QGraphicsItem`s are positioned in a linear fashion on the scene. I've tried using the approach below:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QBrush>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QGraphicsLayoutItem>
#include <QGraphicsLinearLayout>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsWidget>
#include <QPen>

class MyShape : public QGraphicsRectItem, public QGraphicsLayoutItem {
  public:
    MyShape(void) {
        setPen(QPen(QBrush(Qt::black), 1));
        setBrush(QBrush(Qt::green));
        setRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
    }

    virtual QSizeF sizeHint(Qt::SizeHint which,
                            const QSizeF& constraint = QSizeF()) const {
        Q_UNUSED(which);
        Q_UNUSED(constraint);
        return boundingRect().size();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QGraphicsScene scene;
    MyShape* shape1 = new MyShape;
    MyShape* shape2 = new MyShape;
    MyShape* shape3 = new MyShape;
    scene.addItem(shape1);
    scene.addItem(shape2);
    scene.addItem(shape3);

    QGraphicsLinearLayout* layout = new QGraphicsLinearLayout;
    layout->addItem(shape1);
    layout->addItem(shape2);
    layout->addItem(shape3);

    QGraphicsWidget* container = new QGraphicsWidget;
    container->setLayout(layout);
    scene.addItem(container);

    QGraphicsView view;
    view.setScene(&scene);
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

This doesn't work, as all items are still placed on top of each other, instead of next to each other (according to the layout dictated by the linear layout). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I had forgotten to override the `setGeometry` function!

So the implementation of the `MyShape` class should look like this:

```
class MyShape : public QGraphicsRectItem, public QGraphicsLayoutItem {
  public:
    MyShape(void) {
        setPen(QPen(QBrush(Qt::black), 1));
        setBrush(QBrush(Qt::green));
        setRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
    }

    virtual QSizeF sizeHint(Qt::SizeHint which,
                            const QSizeF& constraint = QSizeF()) const {
        Q_UNUSED(which);
        Q_UNUSED(constraint);
        return boundingRect().size();
    }

    virtual void setGeometry(const QRectF& rect) {
        setPos(rect.topLeft());
    }
};
```

And *now* it works as expected. =)

Comment: Thanks, this helped. BTW, you can accept this answer ;)